# Magento not able to assign Rewrite Reports Product Viewed block

Tags: magento

I just need to create recent Product View Slider.
So i want to overide Reports_Product_Viewed block from core file.
I wrote config.xml for this but on product page I ma not able to do this.
Basically I want to overide Reports product block and want to append some code in that for the recent product slider.
    my config.xml is

```
    ----------------
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Deepak_Recent>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Deepak_Recent>
        </modules>

        <global>
            <blocks>
                <recent>
                    <rewrite>
                        <reports_product_viewed>Deepak_Recent_Block_Product_Viewed</reports_product_viewed>
                    </recent>
                </catalog>
            </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <recent>
                <class>Deepak_Recent_Helper</class>
            </recent>
        </helpers>

         </global>
       <frontend>
             <routers>
                            <recent>
                                    <use>standard</use>
                                    <args>
                                          <module>Deepak_Recent</module>
                                          <frontName>recent</frontName>
                                    </args>
                            </recent>
                    </routers>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <recent>
                          <file>recent.xml</file>
                    </recent>
                </updates>
                </layout>
            </frontend>
    </config>

my rewrite block
-----------------

    <?php 

    class Deepak_Recent_Block_Product_Viewed extends Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed{
        public function getme(){  echo 'block loaded';}
    }

my layout.xml

    ---------------
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block type="recent/product" name="product.info.recent" template="carousel/products_recent_horizontal.phtml"/>
            </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
    </layout>

and alst my phtml file
-----------------
<?php 

echo $this->getme();exit;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `config.xml` file should be

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Deepak_Recent>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Deepak_Recent>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks> 
            <reports>  <!-- Changes here start -->
                <rewrite>
                    <product_viewed>Deepak_Recent_Block_Product_Viewed</product_viewed>
                </rewrite>
            </reports> <!-- Changes here end -->               
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <recent>
                <class>Deepak_Recent_Helper</class>
            </recent>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <recent>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Deepak_Recent</module>
                    <frontName>recent</frontName>
                </args>
            </recent>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <recent>
                    <file>recent.xml</file>
                </recent>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    </config>
```

Actually issue was in

```
           <blocks> 
            <reports>  <!-- Changes here start -->
                <rewrite>
                    <product_viewed>Deepak_Recent_Block_Product_Viewed</product_viewed>
                </rewrite>
            </reports> <!-- Changes here end -->               
        </blocks>
```

Comment: look in top of your answer...modules tag cloased after config..is it right..   <config>
        <modules>
            <Deepak_Recent>
             <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>